# Left homotopy groups

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

What are $\delta_0$ and $\delta_1$ in the diagram of the definition $2.1$
in the notion of homotopy [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are constant functions. For any $x\in X$, we have $\delta_0(x) = 0$ and $\delta_1(x) = 1$.

Comment: OK. An how can I see that $\eta$ is a **natural** transformation?

Comment: @user122424 A natural transformation **between which functors**?